# Обновление файлов css/js

Tags: javascript, css

Есть молодой сайт, на котором приходится постоянно обновлять файлы. Используется фреймворк Flask. Как обеспечить обязательное обновление файлов css и js?

Подключение файла стилей:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/index.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Добавление версии не решает проблему. Файл стилей таким образом просто не добавляется.

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/log_in.css?v=2')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Аналогично файлы js.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/log_in.css')}}?v=2" ...
```